# Elasticsearch on fashion commerce

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, e-commerce

I have the following dataset indexed in elasticsearch

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Red T-shirt",
    "size": "S",
    "styleId": "R-1"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Red T-shirt",
    "size": "M",
    "styleId": "R-1"
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Red T-shirt",
    "size": "L",
    "styleId": "R-1"
},
{
    "id": "4",
    "name": "White T-shirt",
    "size": "S",
    "styleId": "W-1"
},
{
    "id": "5",
    "name": "White T-shirt",
    "size": "XL",
    "styleId": "W-1"
}
]
```

In search result I want products grouped by styleId. Is it possible like bellow sample result? In most of the commerce websites like Amazon, Myntra, Flipkart I have seen they are doing the same what I am trying. I have tried many elasticsearch concepts like "collapse" but without success. Using kibana, and elasticsearch version 7.4. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Red T-shirt",
    "size": "S",
    "styleId": "R-1",
    "sizes": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Red T-shirt",
            "size": "M",
            "styleId": "R-1"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Red T-shirt",
            "size": "L",
            "styleId": "R-1"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "4",
    "name": "White T-shirt",
    "size": "S",
    "styleId": "W-1",
    "sizes": [
        {
            "id": "5",
            "name": "White T-shirt",
            "size": "XL",
            "styleId": "W-1"
        }
    ]
},
]
```

Comment: collapse should work for this.  What is the issue with collapse result?

Comment: Hi Jaspreet, thanks for reply. The problem with collapse is the count of returned records. If the total no of results = 100 and collapse sending me 30 results, still the total records count remains 100 which is a blocker while doing pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [collapse](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html) with cardinality aggregation.
[Cardinality](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) will give group level count

```
{
  "_source": "false",
  "collapse": {
    "field": "styleId.keyword",
    "inner_hits": {
      "name": "group-details",
      "size": 5
      }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 5,
  "aggs": {
    "type_count": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "styleId.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jaspreet, this is a nice approach, but I am receiving only count in the cardinality group, where as I need complete record info.

Comment: @SwadeshBehera full record info will be in inner_hits under collapse

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this approach.

Comment: @SwadeshBehera You can also use terms aggregation with top_hits . Pagination will be easier to handle in collapse

Comment: Jaspreet you are awesome. It worked. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: @SwadeshBehera  Glad could be of help